# Filename argument in Haskell

Tags: haskell

How comes that this is working:

```
module Main where

import System.Environment (getArgs)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B
import Data.ByteString.Char8 (ByteString)

type Field = ByteString
type Row = [Field]
type CSV = [Row]

main :: IO ()
main = do
    contents <- B.readFile "test.csv"
    print (parseCSV contents)

-- used with "./myprogram" to read "test.csv"
```

But not if I replace `"test.csv"` with a command-line argument in `main`:

```
-- ... same as before ...

main :: IO ()
main = do
    contents <- B.readFile $ head getArgs
    print (parseCSV contents)

-- used with "./myprogram test.csv" to read "test.csv"
```

With the latter I get this error at compile time:

```
csv.hs:20:35: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[FilePath]’
                  with actual type ‘IO [String]’
    • In the first argument of ‘head’, namely ‘getArgs’
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘head getArgs’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: contents <- B.readFile $ head getArgs
```

EDIT --
I initially omitted a part of the code, which I thought was not necessary to understand the question. It's corrected now.

Comment: The code you provided does not match the code shown by the error message.

Comment: When I run your first code, it doesn't compile either. @somesoaccount: Laziness shouldn't prevent compilation errors.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs thanks - please check the edit

Comment: @sepp2k I actually made a mistake in the first code - now corrected

Comment: It still doesn't match. There is no `($)` in your example.

Comment: @Jivan Your error message suggests you have no `where` and the contents line actually reads `contents <- B.readFile $ head getArgs`. It is generally tough to debug when the error message doesn't match the code.

Comment: @Alec you're right - fixed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that [`getArgs :: IO [String]`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/System-Environment.html#v:getArgs) is also monadic, so you need to extract it first in the `do` block before trying to get the head of it:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    args <- getArgs                      -- now `args :: [String]`
    contents <- B.readFile (head args)
    print (parseCSV contents)
```

Comment: It works. Honestly I can't say that I really understand exactly **why**, but I'm looking forward to studying it - thanks

Comment: I recommend you look at some monad tutorials - it will probably be confusing at first, but at least it won't be voodoo magic. :)